# Flutter text do not wrap

Tags: flutter

I want to automatically space mathematical characters when using the latext package, but why are they not automatically spaced? Is there any way to handle it? Thanks

This is my problem

[image]

And this is my code

[image: [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBN2H.jpg)]
[image: [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYx13.jpg)]

I want mathematical characters to wrap, is there any way to handle it?
This is my latext code

```dart
    Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        child: LaTexT(
                          laTeXCode: Text(
                            //$A=\left\{ 0;\,1;\,2;\,3;\,4;\,5;\,6;\,7 \right\},E=\left\{\overline{{{a}_{1}}{{a}_{2}}{{a}_{3}}{{a}_{4}}}/{{a}_{1}};{{a}_{2}};{{a}_{3}};{{a}_{4}}\in A,{{a}_{1}}\ne \text{0} \right\}.$
                            widget.question?.content ?? '',
                            maxLines: 3,
                            style:
                                AppStyles.t16b.copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.sp),
                          ),
                        );),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: Can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error. More about [minimal-reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't understand it very well T.T

Comment: can you include code-snippet instead code-image

Comment: Thank you, I just added the snippet code, I hope you can help

Comment: Can you try with increasing `maxLines: 5` or some N?

Comment: i try, but it doesn't work

Comment: can you share a full equation to test on  `laTeXCode`

Answer (score 0):

I've provided horizontal & vertical scrolls for the LaTexT widget.

Try this:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: openDialog,
          child: const Text("Open Dialog"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> openDialog() async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return const AlertDialog(
          title: Text("LaTexT Code"),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: LaTexT(
                laTeXCode: Text(
                  r"What do you think about $L"
                  "'"
                  r" = {L}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ ?"
                  "\n"
                  r"And some display $\LaTeX$: $$\boxed{\rm{A function: } f(x) = \frac{5}{3} \cdot x}$$"
                  "\n"
                  r"$\KaTeX$-Flutter provides easy processing of $LaTeX$ embedded into any text.",
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
}
```